# Al cambiar directorio no funciona shell_exec en PHP

Tags: php, php5

Tengo un problema, el cual consiste que al cambiar la ruta para ejecutar `shell_exec` no funciona.

1.- Este si funciona:

```
<?php 
$ruta = 'C:\ASOFTPV\MariaDB-10\bin\mysql.exe'; 
$usuario = 'root'; 
$contrasena = '1234';
$carpeta='dbname';


$cmd = ''.$nsis_ruta.' -u '.$nsis_usuario.' -p'.$nsis_contrasena.' -e "create database ' . $carpeta . '"';
$salida = shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

2.- Este no funciona:

```
<?php 
$ruta = 'C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysql.exe'; 
$usuario = 'root'; 
$contrasena = '1234'; 
$carpeta='dbname';

$cmd = ''.$nsis_ruta.' -u '.$nsis_usuario.' -p'.$nsis_contrasena.' -e "create database ' . $carpeta . '"';
$salida = shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

El objetivo de este es que el codigo permita ejecutar una shell con diferentes rutas hacia el acceso mysql.exe. El que no funciona esta en otro equipo, la ruta y credenciales estan bien pero no emite ningún error y no crea la base de datos.

Comment: en windows las rutas con espacios hay que ponerlas con " dobles prueba con:
 `$ruta = '"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.1\bin\mysql.exe"';`

Comment: Que lió me había hecho por esto. Gracias, esto soluciono mi problema. Saludos.